# Rational map from a projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry

Let $B$ be a projective variety, and $f: \mathbb P^n\to B$ be any rational map; such that the generic fiber is of dimension at least $2$. I guess the following statement is always true:

> There exists some fiber of $f$, which contains a rational curve.

I guess this because, I think it is a very strong condition for a variety to contain no rational curve. Basically the only counterexample I can think about, are the abelian varieties, and over $\mathbb C$ they are tori, and I believe this cannot happen in our case. However, I have no idea how to prove the statement above.

Any hint, or counterexample would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to expect rational curves on a variety of general type...you might want to look at Kollár's Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties. Quite early on there is a discussion of "finding rational curves" with different methods depending on the positivity of the canonical or anticanonical class.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you, I'll check it.